# ios 8 Photos framework -[performChanges:completionHandler] progression

Tags: ios, ios8, photos, photosframework

I'm saving lot of photos through the new iOS 8 Photos framework, particularly with the `-[PHPhotoLibrary performChanges:completionHandler]` method.

It took some times with large set of images so I need somehow to inform users about the progression of this action but there's nothing like so in documentation.

Anyone already find a way for that ?

Answer (score 0):

`PHPhotoLibrary` is built in a way that performs all changes in the background after launched so you can't track the progress. Use `PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver` protocol to get notified when the changes are saved. If you care about the concrete asset check for it's persistent identifier.

```
NSString *expectedId = ...
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = ...

- (void)photoLibraryDidChange:(PHChange *)changeInstance {
    PHFetchResultChangeDetails *changeDetails = [changeInstance changeDetailsForFetchResult:fetchResult];

    for (PHAsset *asset in [changeDetails.insertedObjects arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:changeDetails.changedObjects]) {
        if ([asset.localIdentifier isEqualToString:expectedId]) {
            // saving has ended
        }
    }
}
```